# Laravel inner join Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to change this MySQL query to Larvel Grammar.

**MySql inner Join**

```
 select u.name , c.title , c.content 
 from users u 
 inner join communities  c on u.id = c.user_id
 where u.name like '%name%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
DB::table('users')
     ->select(['users.name', 'communities.title', 'communities.content'])
     ->join('communities', 'communities.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
     ->where('users.name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont know what do you mean by Larvel Grammar. but i think you thinking about laravel eloquent or query builder:

Your query:

```
 select u.name , c.title , c.content 
 from users u 
 inner join communities  c on u.id = c.user_id
 where u.name like '%name%'
```

Query Builder:

```
 DB::table('users')
     ->select(['name', 'c.title', 'c.content'])
     ->join('communities as c', 'c.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
     ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')
     ->get()
```

Eloquent (if you have those models):

```
User::with('communities')
        ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->get();
```

Note: User model should have communities relation:

```
   public function communities(){
      return $this->hasMany(Community::class);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('tableName')
->join('communities AS c','c.user_id','=','tableName.id')
->where('tableName.name','LIKE','name')
->select('tableName.name','c.title','c.content')
->get();
```

I hope this will help you.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Query builder. Add `use DB;` at the top (in Class) of your controller.

Then use this, When you want to get data.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->join('communities', 'users.id', '=', 'communities.user_id')
                ->select('users.name , communities.title , communities.content')
                ->where('users.name','LIKE','%name%')
                ->get();
```

Comment: public function searchWriter($search){
        return  DB::table('users')
        ->join('communities', 'users.id', '=', 'communities.user_id')
        ->select('users.name , communities.num,communities.country ,communities.title,communities.content,communities.hits,communities.commend,communities.created_at')
        ->where('users.name','LIKE',"%$search%")
        ->get();

    }         // An error is occurring.
I'd like to get the results of my search as a writer.